# Fetch Image and Save To Google App Engine Using Blob

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob

I have image URLs like http://example.com/someimage.png - how do I fetch that image and save it with Blob? Thanks.

Comment: Is your question about fetching the image or about persisting it? What exactly is the problem, did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [example code](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) from the documentation showing how to write a file to the blobstore. You'll have to use a stream instead of a writer, since a PNG image is binary, and you'll have to set the appropriate content type, but it should show you the way.

And here's the [UrlFetch documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/), explaining how to get some available resource on the web, using HTTP.

Comment: what if i have an com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image object, how do i save that to blob, thanks

Comment: No idea. I don't know about GWT. Ask another question.